# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have provided an instance of an incorrect PK class for this find operation.

Tags: jpa, primary-key, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to create a URI and returns an object looking for NIF. (One custom filter)
I have tried to replicate the search by id but does not work, the truth, I'm not sure what I do. I have two classes with these functions

`ClientesAbstractFacade.java`

```
    public T findNif(Object nif) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, nif);
    }
```

`lientesFacadeREST.java`

```
    @GET
    @Path("nif/{nif}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Clientes findNif(@PathParam("nif") String nif) {
        return super.findNif(nif);
    }
```

And here POJO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clientes")
public class Clientes implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
```

As you can see, I'm trying to do custom searches, something easy, and then implement a login.
But I can not even filter by nif, these return error 500

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have provided an instance of an incorrect PK class for this find operation.  Class expected : class java.lang.Integer, Class received : class java.lang.String.

Comment: add tracelog from service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception says it all:

> IllegalArgumentException: You have provided an instance of an incorrect PK class for this find operation.  Class expected : class java.lang.Integer, Class received : class java.lang.String

The `getEntityManager().find(entityClass, nif)` is working on the *Primary Key* column of your Table. This is, as the exception states, an Integer.
I guess you want to use your NamedQueries and have thus to use [createNamedQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNamedQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-)-methods of the `EntityManager`.

So your find-method should look something like that:

```
public T findNif(String nif) {
    return (T) getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Clientes.findByNif", Clientes.class)
              .setParameter("nif", nif).getSingleResult();
}
```

Comment: I think need pass string nif to createnamedquery not?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Query argument nif not found in the list of parameters provided during query execution.

Comment: and return need to cast return (T) getEntityManager and work perfectly